# Jquery accessibility stuffs - how to get focus back on specific element

Tags: jquery, accessibility, setfocus

I am doing accessibility stuffs in my prototype pages.  Here is the scenario i am trying to do.

As part of accessibility process, when I press the enter button while 'Gary Horsley' (blue color marked) hyperlink get focused, the popup window should get invoked as you can see in the below illustration.

[image]

This part I have done.  The thing I want to do is, again when I press the close button of the popup window, the focus return back to respective link where I used to show the popup window.

The same thing needs to be followed for all links i.e. when I press 'John Doe' hyperlink, popup window will get opened up with respective unique content.  Again when I close that popup window, the focus should get back to 'John Doe'.

How can I do this by jQuery?  Anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a global variable to hold the last element id and change focus to it on closing popup

```js
var lastIndex = null;

$(".nameField").click(function() {

  lastIndex = this.id;
  showPopup();

});

$(".closePopup").live("click", function() {

  hidePopup();
  $("#" + lastIndex).focus();

});
```